# particle velocity variable with time

Tags: analysis

Consider two fixed points $A$ and $B$.  At $A$, you have a receiver and at $B$ you have a transmitter.  $B$ continually emits particles towards $B$ at a constant rate.  But the particle velocity is dependent on the time of its emission - i.e. the particle travels with constant velocity towards $A$ but the velocity of it, is dependent on the time of its departure as $v(t)$.  The question is the number of particles $a(t)$ received at $A$ as a function of time.  How do we formulate $a(t)$ in terms of $v(t)$?  Fixed distance between the two points is $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the number of particles emitted per unit time is fixed $$\frac{dp}{dt} = c$$
Then, those emitted at time $t$ are received later at time $t + d/v(t)$ And so at time $t$ you get all those particles that were emitted at earlier times $s$ where $t = s + d/v(s)$ Or $$a(t) = c   \mu |s + d/v(s) = t |  $$

Where $\mu|\cdot|$ is the measure of the solution set in the normal measure on the real line. I don't think you can do better than this without an explicit formula for $v(t)$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why should we have c in the last equation?  I may not able to get.

Comment: I think I may have to understand this concept of measure.